# Retrieve ID PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to retrieve "376901" from the following table:

```
<td class="evn_tdata_l">Reconciliation-Manager_RECON-MGMT_SFTP_T</td>
<td class="evn_tdata_l">376901</td>
```

Right now what I've tried is the following code:

```
    if (preg_match_all("/<td[^>]+?>Reconciliation-Manager_RECON-MGMT_SFTP_T<\/td><td[^>]+?>(.*)<\/td>/s", $html, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo "No se encontró ninguna coincidencia.";
```

I dont see what seems to be wrong, could you please advise?
Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, using a reluctant quantifier here: `[^>]+?>` is useless and will only slow down the regex engine walk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `\s*` between `<td>`

```
/<td[^>]+?>Reconciliation-Manager_RECON-MGMT_SFTP_T<\/td>\s*<td[^>]+?>(.*)<\/td>/sU
```

Comment: The table has more values:

`<td class="evn_tdata_l">Reconciliation-Manager_RECON-MGMT_SFTP_T</td>
  <td class="evn_tdata_l">376901</td>
  <td class="evn_tdata_l">SFTP</td>  
  <td class="evn_tdata_l">host</td>`

When I add the \s* it brings all the <td> tags.

Comment: add U `/sU` to make it ungreedy

Comment: Are you sure that using the U modifier is a good idea (in my opinion this modifier is useless most of the time), for example why do you want to make `\s*` non-greedy? I think that choosing the good quantifier for all cases is better (and more explicit).

Comment: Yes, yuo are right. Didn't think about.some later i'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your pattern is that you doesn't describe the newline and eventually other white-space characters between the first closing tag `</td>` and the following opening tag `<td...`.

But you can use a way that doesn't care about these details and only use the html structure.
As structured datas, you can get the information you want in an XML or HTML content using an xpath query, example:

```
$html = <<<'EOD'
<td class="evn_tdata_l">Reconciliation-Manager_RECON-MGMT_SFTP_T</td>
<td class="evn_tdata_l">376901</td>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//td[@class="evn_tdata_l" and text()="Reconciliation-Manager_RECON-MGMT_SFTP_T"]/following-sibling::td[1]';

$result = $xp->query($query)->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi Casimir, this is working perfect, however when I set the variable $html to the url from where it should retrieve the information it shows the following error:

<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\v2\reportresult.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />

How should I set the URL to this variable? Thank you,

Comment: @AngelPereyra: the parameter of the method `DOMDocument::loadHTML` must be a string with html content, not an url. If you want to get html content from an url, use `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`. See the PHP manual about `DOMDocument` to see all the available methods.